# I can't find out this extra line in array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, var-dump

I don't know what's that mean in my array.

**my code is**

```
   try {

  $conn=new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=moviesite","root","");
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $stmt=$conn->prepare("SELECT movie_name,movie_year,movie_type,movie_leadactor,movie_director
                          FROM movie
                            ORDER BY movie_name,movie_year");
  $stmt->execute();
  $result=$stmt->fetchAll();
  foreach ($result as  $row) {
    var_dump($row);
  }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getmessage();
}


**And my result**
```

[image]

**My Problem is**

```
0 => string 'Bruce Almighty' (length=14)
1 => string '2003' (length=4)
.
.
.
```

I just request for `movie_name`, `movie_year`, `movie_type`, `movie_leadactor`, `movie_director`

but it show me extra line like 0 => string 'Bruce Almighty' (length=14)

Comment: `fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter of `fetchAll()` is `fetch_style` which

> Controls the contents of the returned array as documented in
>   PDOStatement::fetch(). Defaults to value of
>   PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE (which defaults to PDO::FETCH_BOTH)

That's why when you `var_dump($row);`, you got both `numeric` and `associative` format data in your array.You just need to set `$stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);`before your `$stmt->execute();` Or use `$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` for associative index.

```
try {

  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=moviesite","root","");
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT movie_name,movie_year,movie_type,movie_leadactor,movie_director
                          FROM movie
                            ORDER BY movie_name,movie_year");
   //ADD BELOW LINE
  $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $stmt->execute();

  //OR REPLACE BELOW LINE LIKE $result=$stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  $result = $stmt->fetchAll(); 
  foreach ($result as  $row) {
    var_dump($row);
  }
} catch (PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getmessage();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The dump is giving you information about each variable in the array. So hence the type and the amount of characters. If you just want to output them.

```
foreach ($result as  $row) {
    echo $row['movie_name'].','.  $row['movie_year'].','.$row['movie_type'].','.$row['movie_leadactor'].','.$row['movie_director'].'<br />';
}
```

Comment: hi Richard. No , i have some columns with names(movie_name,movie_year,movie_type,movie_leadactor,And movie_director), i want to know what's 0=>string 'Bruce Almighty' , because i don't have any column with name zero(0) Or 1 Or 2 Or 3 Or 4 , what's this lines ?

Answer (score -1):

Change the limit of display childrens

```
; with sane limits
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = 16
xdebug.var_display_max_children = 400
xdebug.var_display_max_data = 2048 


; with no limits
; (maximum nesting is 1023)
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1 
xdebug.var_display_max_children = -1
xdebug.var_display_max_data = -1
```

It can also be done on coding side with following

```
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_depth', 16);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_children', 400);
ini_set('xdebug.var_display_max_data', 2048);
```

Comment: Hi Virk , my question completed in comment for richard , if you know about that please help me . TNX